# Whence אֶת between partners' names?

Tags: etymology, hebrew, prepositions, conjunctions

The word אֶת /et/ is used with the following meanings:

- In Biblical Hebrew, it means "with".  In modern Hebrew it survives, but only with a complement-of-the-preposition pronoun suffix: "with me", "with you", etc.
- In Biblical and modern Hebrew (and points in between), it's the direct-object preposition (no translation in English).
- Afaict newly in modern Hebrew, it's used between partners' names in business names, like משה את דוד (given names) or כהן את לוי (surnames).

My question is about the latter sense: in particular, about its etymology. Does it come from the Biblical "with" sense, from Latin/Romance *et* ("and"), or from where?

Comment: *-at* is a feminizing suffix in semic (or even afro asiatic). I could see it marking the wives name as in Slavic (Ivan-ka; sorry if I'm raiding that horse to death without much understanding of it). Tres cavalier, the wifes name comes first (if not, ignore this).

Comment: @vectory no; you would expect single taw suffixed to the first name for that to work.

Comment: @Keelan thanks for the edit.

Comment: I wonder whether it can be related to PIE e̯eti "also, in addition, besides".

Comment: Such a basic word is unlikely to be borrowed.  Remember too that biblical Hebrew predates the founding of Rome.  There can't have been much cultural contact.  The Hebrew word has no obvious cognate in Arabic.

Comment: @Bert thanks for your input. I'm asking about a modern Hebrew sense, from long after Rome, and a very specific one at that, used only (afaik) in company names, so I wouldn't call it "such a basic word".

Comment: @Anixx Since that IE word apparently has pretty much the same sense as את I wonder what the added value of such a hypothesis would be. A borrowing in recent times is furthermore unlikely because *eti* descendants are not used this way with names and the *t* has dropped out in most if not all descendants.

Comment: @Keelan Latin et "and" comes from e̯eti.

Comment: @Anixx I am aware of that. It looked like msh210 was thinking about a borrowing in recent times, but this is unlikely. A borrowing in ancient times is possible, but again, I'm wondering what the added value of the hypothesis would be since Hebrew already has את in pretty much the same meaning. Or is Latin *et* attested with names as described in the OP?

Comment: @Keelan ampersand is commonly encountered with names, and it is a ligature of "et".

Comment: @Bert Barrois could it be a borrowing from Hittite to the North-Western semitic?

Comment: @Anixx ah yes, for the first example that would work; thanks!

Comment: I will point out that the word את in the sense of "with" is understood to be different from the word עם which also means "with", see my essay on the topic: https://ohr.edu/this_week/whats_in_a_word/8451

Comment: This question was later re-asked on Languages & Linguistics – Codidact, where it got [a good answer](https://languages.codidact.com/a/277074/277087).

Answer (score 1):

To give a much more global picture abstracting from the history of the Hebrew language: The change of a commitative adposition "with" to a coordinating conjunction "and" is not unusual and often seen in the languages of the world. There are lots of languages that don't have different words for the two functions, for a high level overview see [WALS chapter 63](https://wals.info/chapter/63).